# displaying image in grid view column of aspx page with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, gridview

I need to display an image based on a condition in gridview column, if the gridview column is "Processed" i need to display an tick image if not i need to display x image..

my aspx page code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="90px" ItemStyle-Width="0">
        <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("StatusName")%>//here the status name loads like Processed,Failed,..
          <br />
          <%#Eval("Comments")%>
        </ItemTemplate>

<HeaderStyle Width="90px"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle Width="0px"></ItemStyle>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally set the `ImageUrl` attribute for an image element like so:

Eg:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="90px" ItemStyle-Width="0">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("StatusName")%>//here the status name loads like Processed,Failed,..
    <asp:Image runat="server"
       ImageUrl='<%# 
         (Eval("StatusName").Equals("Processed") ? "tick.png" : "cross.png") 
       %>' />
    <br />
    <%#Eval("Comments")%>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```